# Save entire grid layout as image or PDF, not just last plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there anyway to save an entire layout and not just the last plot pushed onto the grid?

For example:

```
a <- (ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point())
b <- (ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, cyl)) + geom_point())
c <- (ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, disp)) + geom_point())
d <- (ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, qsec)) + geom_point())

vplayout <- function(x,y){
  viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
}

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2,2)))
print(a, vp = vplayout(1,1))
print(b, vp = vplayout(2,1))
print(c, vp = vplayout(1,2))
print(d, vp = vplayout(2,2))
```

Is there a way to save an image or pdf of the all four plots together, as opposed to just the bottom right plot.

Thank you.

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. What are you getting? I placed a `pdf` call before the `grid.newpage()` command and `dev.off()` after the last print, so maybe it is a viewer issue.

Comment: Also why not just use a `facet_wrap`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the graphical device of your choosing:

```
png()
library(grid) # not loaded by default
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2,2)))
print(a, vp = vplayout(1,1))
print(b, vp = vplayout(2,1))
print(c, vp = vplayout(1,2))
print(d, vp = vplayout(2,2))
dev.off()
```

[image]

I did it with the `png()` device so I could paste it here, but the `pdf()` device works just as well.